# How do I get the name of a user from its ID (SQL Joins)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

It's hard to get a good title for this question, but i will explain it thoroughly below. I'll be simplifying these tables a bit to make the question a bit easier to ask.

I have a table called 'User' with the following columns:

```
UserRowId (PK)
FirstName
LastName
RegionRowId (FK)
Active
```

I have a table called 'Region' with the following columns:

```
RegionRowId
RegionDesc
UserRowId
```

The logic here is, a user belongs to a 'Region' which is noted by the RegionRowId in the User table. Each region (in the 'Region' table) has a regional manager which is noted by the 'UserRowId' column in the 'Region' table (a FK from the 'User' table).

I have a table called 'UserTime' with the following columns:

```
UserTimeRowId (PK)
UserRowId (FK)
Hours
Sales
```

The logic here is a user (mapped by UserRowId) reports hours and sales which get stored in this table. Each time a user reports sales/hours, a new row is created.

**What I'm trying to accomplish:**

I'm trying to write a query that will pull the FirstName, LastName, the regional manager for this user, the sum of the hours, and the sum of the sales.

**Here's what i have so far:**

Query:

```
SELECT dbo.[User].FirstName, dbo.[User].LastName,
dbo.[Region].UserRowId AS RegManager, dbo.[Region].RegionDesc AS Desc,
SUM(dbo.[UserTime].Sales) AS Sales, SUM(dbo.[UserTime].Hours) AS Hours
FROM dbo.[UserTime]
INNER JOIN dbo.[User] ON dbo.[UserTime].UserRowid = dbo.[User].UserRowId
INNER JOIN dbo.[Region] ON dbo.[User].RegionRowId = dbo.[Region].RegionRowId
WHERE dbo.[User].Active = 1
GROUP BY dbo.[User].FirstName, dbo.[User].LastName,
dbo.[Region].UserRowId, dbo.[Region].RegionDesc
```

Output (example):

```
FirstName   LastName   RegManager   RegionDesc   Sales   Hours
Bob         Man        773          NYC          500     5
```

**What i am having trouble with is:**

I cannot (for the life of me) get the LastName of the regional manager (RegManager column in the output above) instead of the UserRowId. I know in my query i am pulling dbo.[Region].UserRowId so obviously that's what i'll get in the output. However, what i need is to use that ID to cross-reference the User table to pull the name of that manager.

When i try to join the user table and the region table by the UserRowId, i get a list of regional managers instead of a list of users, and a column of the regional managers for that user.

Do i need a subquery in there to accomplish this?

Any help is appreciated and please let me know if I need to clarify anything to get to a solution.

Thank you

Comment: +1 for the well done question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need subqueries, but you need to use aliases, so that you can JOIN the same table (the user table in this case) multiple times without creating an ambiguity.

```
SELECT u.FirstName, u.LastName,
m.FirstName AS RegManagerFirstName, m.LastName AS RegManagerLastName, r.RegionDesc AS [Desc],
SUM(ut.Sales) AS Sales, SUM(ut.Hours) AS Hours
FROM dbo.[UserTime] AS ut
INNER JOIN dbo.[User] AS u ON ut.UserRowid = u.UserRowId
INNER JOIN dbo.[Region] AS r ON u.RegionRowId = r.RegionRowId
INNER JOIN dbo.[User] AS m ON r.UserRowid = m.UserRowId
WHERE u.Active = 1
GROUP BY u.FirstName, u.LastName, m.FirstName, m.LastName, r.RegionDesc
```

Answer (score 2):

What you need to do is JOIN the `User` table in again, using the `UserRowId` in the `Region` table, and alias it so it can reference it separately from the other `User` table you've joined in:

```
SELECT dbo.[User].FirstName, dbo.[User].LastName,
Manager.FirstName AS RegManagerFirstName, Manager.LastName AS RegManagerLastName, dbo.[Region].RegionDesc AS Desc,
SUM(dbo.[UserTime].Sales) AS Sales, SUM(dbo.[UserTime].Hours) AS Hours
FROM dbo.[UserTime]
INNER JOIN dbo.[User] ON dbo.[UserTime].UserRowid = dbo.[User].UserRowId
INNER JOIN dbo.[Region] ON dbo.[User].RegionRowId = dbo.[Region].RegionRowId
INNER JOIN dbo.[User] Manager ON dbo.[Region].UserRowId = Manager.UserRowId
WHERE dbo.[User].Active = 1
GROUP BY dbo.[User].FirstName, dbo.[User].LastName, Manager.FirstName, 
Manager.LastName
```

Comment: Aren't the `dbo.[User].`* ambiguous and need an alias as well?

Comment: @Lucero Not in my experience with SQL Server 2008. Aliasing just one of them means that there's still only one table that's being referred to by `dbo.[User]`, so there's no confusion.

Comment: Right, tried it, I wasn't aware that the alias replaces the name, not just adds another name that can be queried. Still, I think using aliases throughout is a good idea.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist - Actually, i had a problem with your solution when i tried it on management studio. It was having trouble bounding the User columns, which i assume is due to some ambiguity. I tried Lucero's solution and it worked. I still gave you an up tick because your answer was still valuable and fast. Thank you!